# Android studio not found R.id.****

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

It has worked fine till now, but I apparently touched something and something  happened.
Android Studio did not found R.id.**** and R.layout.****.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVZun.png]

What do I need to do to resolve the problem?

Comment: It seems you deleted a layout...

Comment: check layout file exists

Comment: The layout remains as it is . It is doesnt found the layout too.

Comment: I think you deleted `layout\activity_parentscreen.xml`

Comment: The layout remains as it is . It is doesnt found the layout too.

Comment: Then go to Build -> Clean Project, then Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: Clean and rebuilt your project.

Comment: look at imports if android-studio has added a different import ....R

Comment: if you hold ctrl or command and click on R.ID.**** it will take you to component see if that's still happening

Answer (score 16):

I got the same error and just found out I imported automatically `android.R`. I just had to remove it.

Check if you have `import android.R` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 2):

check  build.gradle(app). if there is not `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions`' on top of page include it. That works for me.

or type id `'kotlin-android-extensions'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to undo(ctrl+z) whatever you did accidentally or go to build-> rebuild project.
or build-> clean project or press ctrl+alt+y.

Answer (score 0):

resync gradle, it will solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Think Your R.java is not getting build properly due to some error. Clean your project and Check if there is some error while rebuilding the project.

Answer (score 0):

You may import android.R at the top of your activity and use it in a command.
Clear this import and use android.R.*** in that command and you can see R.layout.*** and R.id.*** in other commands can work.